# Google Transport Tacker Backend tutorial is timing out how can log why?

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-shell

I am following this tutorial by Google [Transport Tracker Backend](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/transport-tracker-backend/#3)

I am at the part "Plotting out Bus Routes" part and it is timing out.

I run this command in the terminal

```
npm run generate_paths
```

It hangs and returns

> Processing trip 1 of 847timeout

Here is the code:

PACKAGE.JSON

```
{


"name": "transport-tracker-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "The server component for Transport Tracker",
  "scripts": {
    "main": "node main.js",
    "generate_paths": "node generate_paths.js"
  },
  "author": "Brett Morgan",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google/maps": "^0.5.5",
    "@mapbox/polyline": "^1.0.0",
    "asyncawait": "^1.0.7",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "csv-parse": "^2.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

GENERATE_PATHS.JSON

```
/*eslint-disable no-shadow-global, unknown-require, no-undef-expression*/
const mapsApiKey = require('./tracker_configuration.json').mapsApiKey;
const {GTFS} = require('./gtfs');
const gtfs = new GTFS();
const _async = require('asyncawait/async');
const _await = require('asyncawait/await');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const moment = require('moment');
const polyline = require('@mapbox/polyline');
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
  key: mapsApiKey,
  Promise
});

function generate_paths() {
  const trips = _await(gtfs.getTripsOrderedByTime());
  const tripsWithLocations = [];
  trips.forEach((trip, tripIndex) => {
    logProgress(`Processing trip ${tripIndex + 1} of ${trips.length}`);
    const timeCursor = moment(
      `${trip.departure_date} ${trip.departure_time}`,
      'YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss'
    );
    const tripPoints = [];
    const stopInfo = _await(gtfs.getStopInfoForTrip(trip.trip_id));
    const stops = [];
    stopInfo.forEach(stop => {
      stops.push({lat: stop.lat, lng: stop.lng});
    });
    const request = {origin: stops[0], destination: stops[stops.length - 1]};
    if (stops.length > 2) {
      request['waypoints'] = stops.slice(1, -1);
    }
    var response = _await(googleMapsClient.directions(request).asPromise())
      .json;
    if (response.status === 'OK') {
      const route = response.routes[0];
      route.legs.forEach(leg => {
        leg.steps.forEach(step => {
          const durationInSeconds = step.duration.value;
          const points = polyline.decode(step.polyline.points);
          const secondsPerPoint = durationInSeconds / points.length;
          points.forEach(point => {
            tripPoints.push({
              time: timeCursor.format('YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss'),
              location: {lat: point[0], lng: point[1]}
            });
            timeCursor.add(secondsPerPoint, 'seconds');
          });
        });
      });
      tripsWithLocations.push({trip: trip, points: tripPoints});
    } else {
      logProgress(' ERROR: ' + response.status);
      process.stdout.write('\n');
      process.exit(1);
    }
  });
  fs.writeFileSync('paths.json', JSON.stringify(tripsWithLocations));
  logProgress('Paths written successfully to paths.json.');
  process.stdout.write('\n');
}

function logProgress(str) {
  // A little bit of readline magic to not fill the screen with progress messages.
  readline.clearLine(process.stdout, 0);
  readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0, null);
  process.stdout.write(str);
}

_async(() => {
  generate_paths();
})().catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the error, "Processing trip 1 of 847timeout."

I found that to use the Direction API, billing needed to be enabled.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-and-billing

After enabling billing, generate_paths ran flawlessly.